# (MVC) Get Latitude, Longitude from Controller for the MapView? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Hi guys i have a model like this (Position):

```
namespace moBelegDAL.Models
{
    public class Position : Entity
    {
        public int PositionId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public double Accuracy { get; set; }
        public double Altitude { get; set; }
        public bool AltitudeValid { get; set; }
        public double Heading { get; set; }
        public bool HeadingValid { get; set; }
        public double Speed { get; set; }
        public bool SpeedValid { get; set; }
        public double NumSatellites { get; set; }
        public bool NumSatellitesValid { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Hi guys i have a controller like this (LocationController):

```
namespace moBelegGUI.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class LocationController : BootstrapBaseController
    {
        public double latitude;
        public double longitude;



        public ActionResult OverView(Position position)
        {
            latitude = position.Latitude;
            longitude = position.Longitude;
            ViewBag.Latitude = latitude;
            ViewBag.Longitude = longitude;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And i have a View like this (OverView):

```
<body onload="GetMap();">

    <script type="text/javascript"> function GetMap() { }</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function GetMap() {

        var latitude = @ViewBag.Latitude;
        var longitude = @ViewBag.Longitude;


        // Set the map and view options, setting the map style to Road and
        // removing the user's ability to change the map style
        var mapOptions =
            {
                credentials: "Al64oUurZOV-AyLUdQI0i0BSPC76kcJc4M2rmA9rSi8VtKhu0GH-qBjVhu4AlzvE",
                height: 400, width: 960, mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,

                //Edit the Views of the Map
                showMapTypeSelector: true,
                enableSearchLogo: false,
                enableClickableLogo: false,
                showDashboard: true
            };

        // Initialize the map
        var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), mapOptions);

        //Hardcode Location with Marker
        var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude), null);
        map.entities.push(pushpin);
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, "mouseup", ZoomIn);

        //Function for zoom to the Marker
        function ZoomIn(e) { }


    }

    </script>
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server">
    </asp:Literal>

</body>
```

The Overview is only a Bing Map with a hardcoded location.
How can i get the right location (lat, long) in the Overview from my Model.

Comment: use ViewBag or ViewData

Comment: Pass you model to the view and then assign the values to javascript variables for use in the script

Comment: @Anand How do you mean that?

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you show me an example please how you mean that? im new with MVC

Comment: In the controller - `return View(position);` and in the view -` @model  Position` and  `new Microsoft.Maps.Location(@Model.latitude,@Model longitude)` (note you already have a model, so no point using `ViewBag`)

Comment: @LukasReiner, I have posted my answer, the variables ViewBag and ViewData are there to pass data between controller and view. Please refer this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-cplusViewBagplusandplusTem

Comment: i have updated now my question with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to pass data from controller would be something like this

```
 public ActionResult OverView(Position position)
        {
             latitude = position.Latitude;
             longitude = position.Longitude;

             //Passing the latitude and longitude values of last element in latitude and longitude lists
             ViewBag.Latitude = latitude;
             ViewBag.Longitude = longitude;
             return View();
        }
```

JavaScript would be like:

```
<body onload="GetMap();">

    <script type="text/javascript"> function GetMap() { }</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function GetMap() {

        var latitude = @ViewBag.Latitude;
        var longitude = @ViewBag.Longitude;

        // Set the map and view options, setting the map style to Road and
        // removing the user's ability to change the map style
        var mapOptions =
            {
                credentials: "Al64oUurZOV-AyLUdQI0i0BSPC76kcJc4M2rmA9rSi8VtKhu0GH-qBjVhu4AlzvE",
                height: 400, width: 960, mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,

                //Edit the Views of the Map
                showMapTypeSelector: true,
                enableSearchLogo: false,
                enableClickableLogo: false,
                showDashboard: true
            };

        // Initialize the map
        var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), mapOptions);

        //Hardcode Location with Marker
        var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude), null);
        map.entities.push(pushpin);
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, "mouseup", ZoomIn);

        //Function for zoom to the Marker
        function ZoomIn(e) { }


    }

    </script>
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server">
    </asp:Literal>

</body>
```

Comment: ok thats a nice idea. i have now one problem. this lat and long are lists of lat and longs. how can i say lat and long that they should only select the last retrived position in the list? I hope you know what i mean

Comment: @LukasReiner, I have modified my answer to use the last retrieved position

Comment: This might work but my worry here is if latitude is a double and position.Latitude is a list of doubles this will error. Also where you say ViewBag.Latitude = latitude[latitude.Count-1]  this will error on an empty sequence.  I think it's better to pop the value straight into viewbag like this:  ViewBag.latitude = position.Latitude, and then if you want the last one then say ViewBag.latitude = position.Latitude.LastOrDefault(); which won't error on an empty sequence

Comment: if latitude is double and Position.Latitude is a list then they are incompatible, you will not be able to compile your project. Do you really need the variables latitude and longitude?

Comment: @D.Mac, we can directly assign the value to view bag as you said if there is no use for variables latitude and longitude. The user may perform some operations on the lists latitude and longitude before passing them to viewbag without modifying the original values in position list

Comment: @LukasReiner, If the `Latitude` property of `Position` is a collection then you code wont work anyway - you cannot pass a complex object to a GET method where the object contains properties which are complex objects or collections (binding will fail and your properties will be null)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, isn't it possible with custom model binders ?

Comment: @Anand, If OP has not worked out this, I don't think he's is ready to start creating custom `ModelBinders` :) - but in any case, a collection should never be passed to a get method. If the collection is large, the query string limit could be exceeded and throw an exception (not to mention the ugly query string it generates)

Comment: i show you my model for more information. I have a Model whitch is connectet with my databank. one Controller who work with this Model and the Overview witch need the lat and long from the controller. i will edit my question with the model so you can see what i mean

Comment: @LukasReiner, modified my answer, you have only posted code for Position class. Your requirement or problem with code is not explained